# Need Help in programming using selenium

Tags: selenium, url, get

I have a problem is I can not store the value of href on the page

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://xxx.xx/RLS?mid=-1050286007&guid=53v90152oyA8bDg&lid=26527875" clinkid="26527875"></a>
```

How can I take the value of href using findElement ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `getAttribute` after finding element as below :-

```
String href = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[clinkid = '26527875']")).getAttribute("href");
```

**Edited 1**:- if `clinkid` dynamically generated try using by visible link text as below :-

```
String href = driver.findElement(By.linkText("your link text")).getAttribute("href");
```

or

```
String href = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("your link text")).getAttribute("href");
```

or

```
String href = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[target = '_blank']")).getAttribute("href");
```

**Edited 2** :- if you want query string from url, you should implement `java.net.URL` to parse it into url and then use `getQuery()` to get query string as below :-

```
URL url = new URL(href);
String queryStr = url.getQuery();
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thank you . But I have a problem is that the numbers in the link automatically variable, I can not determine the value of fixed .

Comment: @Dookin ok then you can try using `By.linkText("visible link  text")`..

Comment: i need to href link has substring "RLS?mid" in it. How can I do this?

Comment: @Dookin Means you want this :- `RLS?mid=-1050286007&guid=53v90152oyA8bDg&lid=26527875`???